# Why I am not able to echo 'sort=name<string>'?

Tags: php

This is a weird issue.

I just trying to print/create a string like below :

```
sort="name<string>"
```

so I just do

```
echo 'sort="name<string>"';
```

however, it seems that PHP store it as :

```
sort="name"
```

What do I miss?

Comment: Are you looking at it with your browser, perhaps?

Comment: You could also consider adding `header('Content-Type: text/plain');` at the top of your script to force verbatim output.

Comment: my bad. fixing bugs in the middle of night is surely not a good thing to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
echo htmlspecialchars('sort="name<string>"', ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
echo 'sort="name&lt;String&gt;"';
```